# Propositional Theorem Proving

Tags: logic, breadth-first-search, theorem-proving

How can we use Breadth First Search as a strategy for propositional theorem proving (I can't see a clear problem formulation: what are the actions available at each state and what a state is).

I've been looking for explanations everywhere in the net; all documents mention BFS but none of them gives an algorithm.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what you're trying to achieve?  'propositional theorem proving' is a fairly huge domain, and you've given almost zero detail.

Answer (score 1):

A state is a list of derivations. A transition from state to state applies an inference rule where each premise appears as a conclusion in the list of derivations and extends the list with the new derivation.

With these states and transitions, you can do a usual BFS until you hit the conclusion you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give a concrete example or a link to a tutorial?

Comment: Search for "forward chaining".

Comment: forward chaining!!! what's the connection?!

Comment: applying rules to assumptions :-)